# Return number of epochs for EarlyStopping callback in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Is there any way to return the number of epochs after which the training was stopped in Keras when using the [`EarlyStopping` callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping)?

I can get the log of the training and validation loss and compute the number of epochs myself using the patience parameter, but is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`EarlyStopping.stopped_epoch`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L461) attribute: remember the callback in a separate variable, say `callback`, and check `callback.stopped_epoch` after the training stopped.

Comment: Note that if you set `restore_best_weights=True` on the EarlyStopping, stopped_epoch will not return the number of epochs that correspond with the best_weights found, just the number of epochs that early stopping halted training.

Answer (score 7):

Subtracting the `patience` value from the total number of epochs - as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852241/return-number-of-epochs-for-earlystopping-callback-in-keras#comment106152010_51674554) - might not work in some situations. For instance, if you set `epochs=100` and `patience=20`, if the best accuracy/loss value is found at epoch 90, the training will stop at epoch 100. So with this approach you would get a wrong number (100-20 = 80).

Moreover, as noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852241/return-number-of-epochs-for-earlystopping-callback-in-keras#comment105540657_49859859), using `EarlyStopping.stopped_epoch` only gives you the epoch when the training has been stopped, but NOT the epoch when the best weights are saved. This is particularly useful when you set `save_best_weights=True` or rely on `ModelCheckpoint` to save the best model before stopping the training.

Therefore my solution is to get the index of model history array, with the best value. Assuming that the metric used is the validation accuracy, relying on `numpy`, here is some code:

```
import numpy as np

model.fit(...)
hist = model.history.history['val_acc']
n_epochs_best = np.argmax(hist)
```

Comment: If in `EarlyStopping` you specified a `min_delta` parameter, `np.argmax` might not find the returned epoch for the best weights. Is it safer to use `EarlyStopping.stopped_epoch-patience+1`

Answer (score 4):

You can also leverage History() call back to find out the number of epochs it was ran for. Ex:

```
from keras.callbacks import History, EarlyStopping

history = History()
callback = [history, EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, verbose=1, min_delta=1e-4)]

history = model.fit_generator(...., callbacks=callbacks)
number_of_epochs_it_ran = len(history.history['loss'])
```

Comment: Good solution. If we used EarlyStopping, we can find the epoch with the best weights by subtracting the 'patience' value from your `number_of_epochs_it_ran`, unless `number_of_epochs_it_ran` equals the number of epochs specified in the `fit` method, in which case the EarlyStopping never kicked in.